# no marker showing in my google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

can't seem to make this works

```
function initialize() {
  var myLatlngBDG = new google.maps.LatLng(-6.913947, 107.633825);

  var mapOptionsBDG = {
   zoom: 5,
   center: myLatlngBDG,
   mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
   mapTypeControl: 0
  }
   var mapBDG = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-BDG'), mapOptionsBDG);

   var markerBDG = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: myLatlngBDG,
  map: mapBDG,
  title: 'PT. Buana Citra Abadi Bandung'
  });

};
 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

the map itself is displayed, but the markes does not appear, and so is the title
according to [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers) I need to write `marker.setMap()` to show marker, but as you can see I already write it

if the problem itself is not in the javascript then this might be the problem

the order including the script in HTML :

```
<html>
<<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/map.css"/>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB8k-8ztQ6Vk34XP6OEBMZ7PryuMx8jjX8&callback=initMap"></script>
<script src="js/map.js"></script>
</html>
```

**NEW PROBLEM** 
why is the map sometimes appears sometimes disappears? I mean when I refresh the page, it disappears, the I refresh several times and it re appears

Comment: It looks like you defined `mapBDG` inside of `initialize()`, but then try to use it outside of the function? What is `marker`? You already set `mapBDG` as the value to the `map` key of `markerBDG` inside the `initialize` function.

Comment: @J.Titus right, sorry I should've write `markerBDG.setMap();` but then it's still not showing any marker  `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);` means that the web runs this function when window loads but just the marker does not appears

Comment: Can you show the html file, and the order you are importing the scripts ?

Comment: @DarwinMedina there... the first one is css file for styling the map

Comment: I edit my answer and just in case delete the `&callback=initMap` and the end of your maps script import, if you doesn't have a initMap function

Comment: seriously why downvote? it's true that my marker did not appear in google map. so I need to rewrite the script to be exactly like the accepted answer in order to make it to work. but why downvote? there should be other people experiencing the same problem as me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that everything is fine, take this code as an example and check yours maybe you find any difference

```js
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", function () {
    var myLatlngBDG = new google.maps.LatLng(-6.913947, 107.633825);

    var mapOptionsBDG = {
        zoom: 5,
        center: myLatlngBDG,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        mapTypeControl: 0
    }
    var mapBDG = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-BDG"), mapOptionsBDG);

    var markerBDG = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlngBDG,
        map: mapBDG,
        title: 'PT. Buana Citra Abadi Bandung'
    });

    markerBDG.setMap(mapBDG);
});
```

```css
#map-BDG{
  width:500px;
  height:300px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Maps Example</h1>
    <div id="map-BDG"></div>
    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB8k-8ztQ6Vk34XP6OEBMZ7PryuMx8jjX8"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: tried this too. I figured that I need to use that setMap() inside the function but still. it's not showing the marker

Comment: this isn't working too, beside I don't need the `setMap()` function since `map : mapBD` already set the marker, atleast supposedly

Comment: I don't know why, but you need to run the snippet two time to make it work